# Rowwise statistics of a dataframe containing several columns with NAs in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, statistics, summary

**Overview of Problem**

Hello R experts,

I will appreciate your support in solving this.I am trying to compute row calculations of a large data frame -15k rows, 700 columns which include NAs.
I want to calculate the following to represent new columns:Min,Max,Mean,Median,Standard deviaton,variance,
10th percentile,30th percentile,70th perventile,90th percentile

Where there are NA's the computation should skip them. Used na.rm = True in dplyr's rowsie command to no success.

**Code to Load subset of Dataframe**

```
#Please note that the real dataframe has hundreds of columns, so typing each column won't be possible

df<- data.frame(a1=c(1,NA,0,4), a2=c(NA,1,0,6), a3=c(NA,NA,9,3),a4=c(1,NA,NA,4), a5=c(4,NA,NA,6), a6=c(7,NA,9,3),a7=c(1,1,1,1),a8=c(2,2,2,2), a9=c(4,3,3,6), a10=c(7,4,9,3))
df
  a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10
1  1 NA NA  1  4  7  1  2  4   7
2 NA  1 NA NA NA NA  1  2  3   4
3  0  0  9 NA NA  9  1  2  3   9
4  4  6  3  4  6  3  1  2  6   3
```

**Expected Output**

I will like to get statistics as mentioned above for each row. I get errors when using dplyr's rowwise computation due to the NAs despite using argumemnt "na.rm = True"

```
df
  a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 min mean median max sd variance per10 per30 per70 per90
1  1 NA NA  1  4  7  1  2  4   7   x    x      x   x  x        x     x     x     x     x
2 NA  1 NA NA NA NA  1  2  3   4   x    x      x   x  x        x     x     x     x     x
3  0  0  9 NA NA  9  1  2  3   9   x    x      x   x  x        x     x     x     x     x
4  4  6  3  4  6  3  1  2  6   3   x    x      x   x  x        x     x     x     x     x
```

**Thanks in anticipation for your help and in growing the R community**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df$min<-apply(df,1,min,na.rm=TRUE)
df$mean<-apply(df,1,mean,na.rm=TRUE)
df$median<-apply(df,1,median,na.rm=TRUE)
df$max<-apply(df,1,max,na.rm=TRUE)
df$sd<-apply(df,1,sd,na.rm=TRUE)
df$variance<-apply(df,1,var,na.rm=TRUE)
df$per10<-apply(df,1,quantile,probs=0.1,na.rm=TRUE)
df$per30<-apply(df,1,quantile,probs=0.3,na.rm=TRUE)
df$per70<-apply(df,1,quantile,probs=0.7,na.rm=TRUE)
df$per90<-apply(df,1,quantile,probs=0.9,na.rm=TRUE)
```

of course you could iterate with "eval(parse..)" over the vector of the functions for the same result and less code

Answer (score 1):

I have included only mean and sd columns.You can do similarly for other parameters.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(mean = apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE),
                sd = apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = sd, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response

Answer (score 0):

This question is in the set of commonly asked 'How do I calculate this/these statistics rowwise on (a selection of) columns in a data.frame'.

I thought I'd add a base and dplyr scalable generic approach that can cope with any number of statistics and allows you to select which columns you want to summarize. Note the need for a unique row identifier.

```r
library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- data.frame(
  a1=c(1,NA,0,4), a2=c(NA,1,0,6), a3=c(NA,NA,9,3),a4=c(1,NA,NA,4), a5=c(4,NA,NA,6), a6=c(7,NA,9,3),a7=c(1,1,1,1),a8=c(2,2,2,2), a9=c(4,3,3,6), a10=c(7,4,9,3))


# Base approach
funs_base = function(x) {
  # Exclude missing values
  x <- na.omit(unlist(x))
  # Add desire functions to this vector
  c(
    mean = mean(x),
    median = median(x),
    sd = sd(x)
  )
}

cbind(df, do.call(rbind, apply(
  df, 1, function(x) 
    aggregate(x ~ 1, FUN = funs_base)[,1]
  , simplify = FALSE)))
#>   a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10  mean median       sd
#> 1  1 NA NA  1  4  7  1  2  4   7 3.375    3.0 2.559994
#> 2 NA  1 NA NA NA NA  1  2  3   4 2.200    2.0 1.303840
#> 3  0  0  9 NA NA  9  1  2  3   9 4.125    2.5 4.155461
#> 4  4  6  3  4  6  3  1  2  6   3 3.800    3.5 1.751190



# Dplyr approach
funs_dplyr = function(x) {
  # Exclude missing values
  x <- na.omit(unlist(x))
  # Add desire functions to this dataframe
  data.frame(
    mean = mean(x),
    median = median(x),
    sd = sd(x)
  )
}

df %>% 
  group_by(id = row_number()) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>% # Can choose columns to summarise here
  mutate(stats = purrr::map(data, ~ funs_dplyr(.))) %>% # Calculate summaries
  tidyr::unnest(cols = c(data, stats))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 14
#> # Groups:   id [4]
#>      id    a1    a2    a3    a4    a5    a6    a7    a8    a9   a10  mean median
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1     1    NA    NA     1     4     7     1     2     4     7  3.38    3  
#> 2     2    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     2     3     4  2.2     2  
#> 3     3     0     0     9    NA    NA     9     1     2     3     9  4.12    2.5
#> 4     4     4     6     3     4     6     3     1     2     6     3  3.8     3.5
#> # ... with 1 more variable: sd <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>